# InputFunctionException - wildcard not resolved by expand and input function

Tags: snakemake

I am building a snakemake pipeline which downloads a set (3) of paired fastq files for each sample, concatenates the appropriate reads together and then aligns and calls variants.

I am accessing the run accessions and ftp paths for each sample in a config.yaml file (although I also have in text files). The initial, troublesome part of the code is as follows:

```py
configfile:"config.yaml"
import pandas as pd
sampleseq = pd.read_csv("data/sample_seq_headers.csv")
ox_codes = sampleseq.ox_code

rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/variants/{ox_code}/results/variants/variants.vcf.gz", ox_code=ox_codes)


ruleorder: download_fastqs > cat_fastqs
wildcard_constraints: ERR="ERR\d+"

rule download_fastqs:
    output:
        "data/reads/{ox_code}/{ERR}_{n}.fastq.gz"
    log:
        "logs/download_ENA/{ox_code}_{ERR}_{n}.log"
    params:
        ftp=lambda wildcards:config['eachrun'][wildcards.ox_code][wildcards.ERR]['ftp_path']
    shell:
        """
        curl {params.ftp}{wildcards.n}.fastq.gz -s -S --retry 10 --retry-delay 10 > data/reads/{wildcards.ox_code}/{wildcards.ERR}_{wildcards.n}.fastq.gz.tmp 2> {log} \
        && mv data/reads/{wildcards.ox_code}/{wildcards.ERR}_{wildcards.n}.fastq.gz.tmp {output} 2> {log}
        """

rule cat_fastqs:
    input:
        expand("data/reads/{{ox_code}}/{ERR}_{{n}}.fastq.gz", ERR=lambda wildcards: config['allruns'][wildcards.ox_code]['ERR'])
    output:
        "data/reads/{ox_code}/merged_{ox_code}_{n}.fastq.gz"
    log:
        "logs/cat_fastqs/{ox_code}_{n}.log"
    shell:
        """
        zcat {input} > {output}
        """
```

The config file is in two parts - 'allruns' and 'eachrun' - and is nested as follows (3 entries for each ERR run):

```yaml
allruns:
  WA-0001:
    country:
    - Ghana
    - Ghana
    - Ghana
    location:
    - XXXX
    - XXXX
    - XXXX
    ERS:
    - ERSXXXXXXX
    - ERSXXXXXXX
    - ERSXXXXXXX
    ERR:
    - ERR1234567
    - ERRXXXXXXX
    - ERRXXXXXXX
    ftp_path:
    - ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR333/002/ERR1234567/ERR1234567_
    - ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERXXXX...........
    - ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERXXXX...........
 WA-XXXX
eachrun:
  WA-0001:
    ERR1234567:
      country: Ghana
      location: XXXXX
      ERS: ERSXXXXXX
      ftp_path: ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR333/002/ERR1234567/ERR1234567_
    ERR2XXXXX:
```

However, I am receiving an InputFunctionException error, as the lambda function within the rule cat_fastqs seems to fail. That or for whatever reason snakemake isnt resolving the ERR wildcard, appropriately. Ive tinkered with the input and output file names as that can help, but it doesn't seem to in this case.

I either get this error...

```
InputFunctionException in line 43 of /home/sanj/projects/XXXX/Snakefile:
KeyError: 'WA-0075'
Wildcards:
ox_code=WA-0075
ERR=WA-0075
n=1
```

or using a wildcard constraint (which i'm not 100% sure is correct)..

```
MissingInputException in line 56 of /home/sanj/projects/XXXX/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule cat_fastqs:
data/reads/WA-0073/ function lambda at 0x7f4b8f0f7170_1 .fastq.gz
```

If anyone had any ideas I would be very grateful.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you verified config file is correct? And have you tried it with minimal config file (i.e. with just 1 or 2 samples)? PS - [`ruleorder`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#handling-ambiguous-rules) doesn't do what you are thinking.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy config file seems to be correct, just tried minimal one (same error) - and i use the same approach to generate the config file as for other snakemake pipelines and they work fine. Have also tried accessing the runs from the pandas dataframe and the same errors occur. Thanks re ruleorder.

Comment: It would be helpful to see error resulting with minimal config file shown here. Error is related to ox code `WA-0075` but relevant config is not present in config shown, which is making it difficult to debug. At quick glance, your code seems fine to me.

Comment: The WA-0075 error was nothing special - every time I ran snakemake a different sample (WA-XXXX) key-error would pop seemingly at random. 

for the time being - as i don't really need the accession information, Ive made three separate downloadfastq rules to download each set of runs, and output them as ERR1,ERR2,  ERR3 for each sample, which I can then at least easily resolve without a lambda function in cat_fastqs. This works fine. 

Still, would love to know where im going wrong.